# How to print drop table result through PDO

Tags: php, pdo, echo

```
$droptable = 'DROP TABLE cars';
  $resultd = $db->prepare($droptable); 
  $resultd->execute();
  $printresult = $resultd->fetchAll();
  

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($printresult); 
  echo "</pre>";
```

I am trying to test something with PDO and created an execute query for the drop table query, but I could not see anything on the screen. Am I making some fundamental programming fundamental or there will be a way around?

Comment: a `drop` statement will not return a recordset

Answer (score 0):

fetchAll will not work, as there are not records generated.

```
  $resultd->debugDumpParams(); // print to screen
 
  /* to push the debug to a var */
  ob_start(); 
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  /* or to just get the error message */
  if($resultd->execute())
    echo " Table deleted ";
  else
    print_r($sql->errorInfo());
```

Answer (score 0):

`DROP` is a DDL (Data Definition Language) statement, it can't possibly return anything.
The statement can succeed or fail. You could manually check the result of every database method call, but you're better off configuring PDO to throw exceptions on error.
It's also unnecessary to prepare the statement since there aren't parameters to bind.

Putting all this together:

```
$db = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
$droptable = 'DROP TABLE cars';
$db->query($droptable);
```

You'll get `PDOException` if something goes wrong or the code will just continue running otherwise. If you really expect the removal to fail now and then during normal operations, you can capture the exception as usual:

```
try {
    $db->query($droptable);
    echo 'Table dropped successfully';
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Could not drop table: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```